# OpenOCD "incorrect checksum in HEX" but the checksum looks okay to me

Tags: hex, stm32, openocd

During flash OpenOCD gives a `Error: incorrect record checksum found in IHEX file` which doesn't make any sense as to me the checksum looks valid.

I was uploading and hex file with success on a stm32l051 mcu using the stm32cubeprogrammer and then i did a script to automatize the hex generation and programming but thing didn't go as planned.
CubeProgrammer had no problem flashing the hex file, OpenOCD on the other hand won't accept my hex file stating the checksums are incorrect but i think they are not.
This is the very very small hex file, and even with this i get errors.
Tried both 2021 version of openOCD I had and the newer 2023 version, same result.

```
:0400000408080000e8
:20040000e44d5fc12278d225a92e2a0020fb59375bd9db2b50b5fb6e5bd9db2b50b5fb6efe
```

OpenOCD command:

```
openocd.exe -s ./openocd/scripts -f ./interface/stlink.cfg -c "transport select hla_swd" -f ./target/stm32l0.cfg  -c "init" -c "reset halt" -c "debug_level 2" -c "program file.hex verify reset exit"
```

OpenOCD output:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0 (2023-02-02) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
hla_swd
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 300 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.263424
Info : [stm32l0.cpu] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32l0.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32l0.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
[stm32l0.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x08006bf4 msp: 0x20002000
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 300 kHz, using 240 kHz
[stm32l0.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x08006bf4 msp: 0x20002000
STM32L0: Enabling HSI16
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2500 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2500 kHz, using 1800 kHz
** Programming Started **
Error: incorrect record checksum found in IHEX file
Error: failed buffering IHEX image, check server output for additional information
** Programming Failed **
shutdown command invoked
```

I wasn't able to understand what's wrong, and by reading the documentation of OpenOCD I did not found any way to ignore the checksum.
I tried doing the calculus manually and using this [online tool](https://www.fischl.de/hex_checksum_calculator/) and checksum looks valid.